# Is there an easier way to make this query?

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper, idictionary

I have two different tables from a DataBase named "empleados" and "fichajes". empleados has the employees data and fichajes has the date and time from when they started working.

I want to get the total work time done by a specific employee between two dates, lets say from 20th to 29th.

I have this query which I use with Dapper on C#:

```
SELECT CONCAT(e.nombre, " " ,e.apellido) as fullName, tfichajes.total 
FROM empleados e 
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT f1.nif, 
                    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(f1.fechasalida) - TIME_TO_SEC(f1.fechaentrada))) AS total 
                    FROM fichajes f1 
                    WHERE f1.fechasalida <= '2019-04-29' 
                    and f1.fechaentrada >= '2019-04-20' 
                    GROUP BY f1.nif
                ) AS tfichajes 
        ON e.nif = tfichajes.nif 
WHERE e.nif = '33333333P'
```

This works just fine, but I was wondering if it was possible to make it simpler.

This is the code I have in my program:

```
public static List<string> CalculaTotalHoras(string nif, DateTime fechaEntrada, DateTime fechaSalida)
{
    var dbCon = DBConnection.Instancia();
    if (dbCon.Conectado())
    {
        string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        using (IDbConnection conexion = dbCon.Conexion)
        {
            var output = conexion.Query($"SELECT CONCAT(e.nombre, \" \" ,e.apellido) as fullName, tfichajes.total " +
                $"FROM empleados e INNER JOIN (SELECT f1.nif, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(f1.fechasalida) - TIME_TO_SEC(f1.fechaentrada))) AS total " +
                $"FROM fichajes f1 where f1.fechasalida <= '{fechaSalida.ToString(format)}' and f1.fechaentrada >= '{fechaEntrada.ToString(format)}' GROUP BY f1.nif) " +
                $"as tfichajes ON e.nif = tfichajes.nif where e.nif = '{ nif }';").ToList();

            var i = 0;
            foreach (IDictionary<string, object> row in output)
            {
                foreach (var pair in row)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        result.Add(pair.Value.ToString());
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.Add(pair.Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    else return null;
}
```

If you have problems with the readability of the code [here](https://gyazo.com/ab624af9fa324ed4d666b69c85905645) you have a gyazo.
[Workingtime](https://gyazo.com/f4a971feaa741220a641c42e1a79d92c) `fichajes` table and [employees](https://gyazo.com/f38e0f24b804eb545984ae8702a60499) `empleados` table.

With that exact query, the expected results are `Alvaro Arguelles 00:05:00`, and in the code, I want to get `Alvaro Arguelles` and `00:05:00` separated in the `result` List.

Did I made it much harder than it actually is?

Comment: Please don't put strings straight into your sql but use parameterized inputs. Else you could be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: *"Is there an easier way to make this query?"* No way to tell without knowing tables structures, example data and expected result.. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for proving those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can be significantly simplified.  Your inner query is selecting ALL employees working in the date in question,  I would start with the INNER query as the main  FROM table getting the data for the one employee. THEN join to the employee to grab the name.

```
select
      CONCAT(e.nombre, " " ,e.apellido) as fullName,
      OneEmp.Total
   from
      ( select
              f1.nif,
              SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(f1.fechasalida) 
                             - TIME_TO_SEC(f1.fechaentrada))) AS total 
           from
              fichajes f1
           where
                  f1.nif = '33333333P'
              AND f1.fechasalida >= '2019-04-20' 
              AND f1.fechasalida <= '2019-04-29' ) OneEmp
         JOIN empleados e
            on OneEmp.nif = e.nif
```

Since your query was summarizing per the one employee, it would only return a single row anyhow.  So the above query will return 1 row, 2 columns... name and total.  Should be able to read those two values back directly.

But as others commented, PARAMETERIZE your query calls.